Using Automapper to Map M:M Relationships in EF Core
I have the following two classes:
public class ADto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<BDto>? BSet { get; set; }
}

public class A 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B>? BSet { get; set; }
}

I use Automapper to convert the incoming ADto to A, then create A.
AutoMapper mapping profile:
CreateMap<A, ADto>();
CreateMap<B, BDto>();

Code:
public async Task<OperationResultDto> CreateAsync(A aDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create & Map the record
    A a = new();
    mapper.Map(aDto, a);
        
    // Create the object in database
    await repository.CreateAsync(a, cancellationToken);
}   

I get the following error:

SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'base_qamarks' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Now I can solve this issue by doing the following in AutoMapper:
CreateMap<A, ADto>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.BSet, opt => opt.Ignore());

Then the manual assignment:
public async Task<OperationResultDto> CreateAsync(A aDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create & Map the record
    A a = new();
    mapper.Map(aDto, a);
    
    // Manually assign it
    foreach (BDto bDto in A.BSet)
    {
        B? b = await bRepository.GetEntityAsync(bDto.Id, cancellationToken);

        if (b != null)
        {
            a.BSet.Add(b);
        }
    }
            
    // Create the object in database
    await repository.CreateAsync(a, cancellationToken);
}   

This works, but it is additional code and doesn't look good. How do I properly use AtuoMapper to map this?

I was able to resolve it... using a resolver:
public class AResolver : IValueResolver<ADto, A, ICollection<A>>
{
    private readonly IARepository aRepository;

    public CompanyRoleResolver(IARepository aRepository)
    {
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
    }

    public ICollection<A> Resolve(ADto source, A destination, ICollection<A> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<A> aSet = new();

        if (source.ASet != null)
        {
            foreach(var aDto in source.aSet)
            {
                A? a = aRepository.GetEntityAsync(a?.Id ?? -1, CancellationToken.None).Result;
                if (a != null)
                {
                    aSet.Add(a);
                }
            }
        }
        return aSet;
    }
}

Then in the mapping profile:
CreateMap<ADto, A>().ForMember(dest => dest.ASet, opt => opt?.MapFrom<AResolver>())

But you need to register the resolver:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AResolver>();


Automapper's Map call will create instances of A and B. The trouble is that if "B"s are associations to existing rows and not intended to be created as children of A, EF expects each "B" to be a reference to a tracked entity.
If all you care about in A.Bs is that the B references are associated, and not updating the contents of the "B" records then you can Attach the B's, but your repository pattern is more than likely going to get in the way of this. With a scoped DbContext it would look like:
public async Task<OperationResultDto> CreateAsync(A aDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var context = DbContextFactory.Create();
    // include mappings for A and B.
    A a = mapper.Map<A>(aDto);
    
    foreach(var b in a.Bs)
        context.Attach(b);

    context.As.Add(a);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
} 

The caveats here is that the DbContext instance is scoped to just this operation, if it is to the request this code will likely still work, but any operation that might have tracked a B instance being attached could result in an exception about an instance of B already being tracked. Such an exception would be situational and come up at runtime. If using a request-scoped DbContext then you need to search the tracking cache first and substitute if found to be safe. For instance if using an injected, request-scoped DbContext instead of a factory-created using scoped instance:
public async Task<OperationResultDto> CreateAsync(A aDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // include mappings for A and B.
    A a = mapper.Map<A>(aDto);
    
    foreach(var b in a.Bs)
    {
        B? existingB = _context.Bs.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = b.Id);
        if(existingB != null)
        {
           a.BSet.Remove(b);
           a.BSet.Add(existingB);
        }
        else
            _context.Attach(b);
    }
    _context.As.Add(a);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
} 

Ugly, and likely even uglier when abstracting the DbContext with a repository.
Instead what I generally recommend when inserting associations to be safe:
public async Task<OperationResultDto> CreateAsync(A aDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var bIds = aDto.BSet.Select(b => b.Id).ToList();

    A a = mapper.Map<A>(aDto); // with just ADto mapping
    
    var bs = await _context.Bs
        .Where(b => bIds.Contains(b.Id))
        .ToListAsync();
    foreach(var b in bs)
        a.BSet.Add(b);

    _context.As.Add(a);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();        
}   

This means that the Dto sent to the "Create" method can be simplified to just passing the BIds to associate with the new A rather than sending completely serialized B DTOs. We don't have to worry about tracked instances, and this can also be worked into your Repository abstraction a bit easier. This avoids a Select N+1 where your initial solution was running a query for each B in a loop by fetching them all in one call.
When doing update scenarios where you may be adding or removing associations of B, you want to fetch the A including all currently associated Bs, determine which Bs need to be added or removed, then removed any Bs that aren't in the DTO list and fetch the Bs to add from the DbContext to be added to the BSet collection. It is not a matter of replacing the list of A.BSet with the new set of Bs, that will result in either exceptions or duplicate data being inserted.
Worth noting that the initial Map(src, dest) implementation you were calling is useful for Update scenarios for entities where you fetch the existingA from the database then call .Map(aDto, existingA) to transfer expected values from the DTO to the entity. For creating an instance of A (insert) then you can simplify it to Map<A>(aDto).

It is a good answer, but unfortunately my context is abstracted away behind a Repository implementation.
